# Defining an interface explicitly

Tags: c#, interface

Visual studio tells me that I dont implement the methods if I dont declare them "explicitly" in terms of interface. 
Here are my methods:

```
    public interface IGetMenus
{
    List<Menu> GetMyMenus();
    void InsertMenu(string topic, string subTopic);
    void UpdateMainMenu(int menu_id, string topic);
    void UpdateSubMenu(int menu_id, string topic);
}
```

Here is an example of how visual studio wants me to implement the interface:

```
List<Menu> IGetMenus.GetMyMenus()
  {
  }
```

Why is that?

Comment: Does your class already inherit a class or implement another interface (not `IGetMenus`) that has the same method declarations?

Comment: but where's the class that implements the interface?

Comment: I didnt know that this questioned existed before..I know why to implement an interface explicitly.. but I dont have methods with the same names...I got it though..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the reason is that you have a method with the same name + parameters but a different return type already.

In C# this is not valid, the only way to implement the interface in this case is to do it explicitly or move/rename the other method.

Answer (score 2):

A good example is a method that you want to make sure the class wants to call. This is usually an expensive method that doesn't add needed functionality.

[ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.getenumerator.aspx) is a good example. You can add, delete, and check items with the implicit methods.
However, Enumerator is defined explicitly.

```
foreach(var item in (ObjectCache as Enumerator))
{
     ...
}
```

So that you don't just enumerate the entire cache without explicitly doing so.

Comment: Very good example, will keep in in mind next time I'm asked why I would need explicit implementations, however in this case the issue seems that VS demands explicit implementation, which is usually do duplicate method signatures

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note when explicitly implementing members, btw, is that there is no way for a derived class to override an explicitly-implemented interface member in its parent class without making that member inaccessible and impossible to chain to (if a `BaseClass` explicitly implements `IFoo.Foo`, the only way for `DerivedClass` to override that is to implement `IFoo.Foo` itself; if the derived class does so, then `IFoo.Foo` will refer to the derived class' method, and there will be no way to access the `IFoo.Foo` implementation in the parent class).  Consequently, if there may be any need for a derived-class member to chain to a parent-class implementation, it's often a good idea to put the "guts" of an interface-member implementation in a `protected virtual` member, and then explicitly implement the interface member so it simply calls the `protected virtual` one.  This will allow derived classes to both override that member and chain to it.